# Quelle est la meilleure tournure: "Il est question de l'endroit où/d'où arrivera l'eau du robinet de la cuisine de notre maison en construction?"

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, constructions

Doit-on écrire "où" ou "d'où" dans la phrase selon le contexte? Si j'avais à repenser la phrase pour éviter d'employer le terme généraliste "endroit", quelle serait la meilleure façon d'exprimer cette idée entre ces deux tournures: "Où sera l'arrivée d'eau" dans la cuisine ou "Où sera la sortie d'eau dans la cuisine"?

merci

Comment: L'arrivée d'eau est le terme adéquat. Quand j'entends "sortie" je pense plutôt à l'évacuation des eaux usées...

Comment: D’abord, je tiens à vous remercier Laurent pour votre commentaire, il est apprécié et utile. Pour ce qui est de « où et d’où », lequel des deux serait adéquat?

Comment: Astuce d'usage : « d'où *vient* » … « où *va* » ; on vient *de* quelque part et on va *ou* on peut. Mais, dans un projet « Où *[sera placée]* l'arrivée d'eau », il n'y a pas de déplacement de l'objet concerné.

Comment: @user25275 As your last two comments are the last in the list you can erase them and rewrite a single comment in which figures your correction.

Comment: @Personne: merci pour l’astuce, elle est appréciée! Pour ce qui est de « arriver », on peut arriver de quelque part et arriver quelque part, non? Les deux pourraient-ils donc convenir dans cette phrase?

Comment: En usage courant : « Elle arrive *de* [point de départ]… » lorsqu'elle est [arrivée] à destination  ; « Elle arrive *à* [destination] … » lorsqu'elle est à proximité de sa destination ; pour de futur « Elle arrivera *là, ici, à* [cet endroit, gauche, droite … ] … ». L'eau arrive *du* puits et arrive *à* l'évier (elle peut y couler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tout dépend de ce qu'on veut dire:

1. > D'où arrivera l'eau de la cuisine ?

   > Elle arrivera du puits qui est dans le jardin / de la nourrice située à l'étage du dessous.
2. > Où arrivera l'eau dans la cuisine ?

   > Elle arrivera à 40 cm de hauteur et à 1 m de la porte, à droite en entrant.

Comme déjà dit en commentaire, on parle plus d'arrivée que de sortie pour l'alimentation en eau donc :

> Où sera l'arrivée d'eau dans la cuisine ?

> Où sera située l'arrivée d'eau dans la cuisine ?